# Merging 3 workbooks into 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i've got 3 workbooks each with indexes that match up, the first has one row per index point but the other 2 workbooks have can have multiple rows per index point for example;

[image]

Ive tried VLOOKUP but that only reurns the first value found for the index not multiple.

Any help would be amazing this is for my uni dissertation and would save me so much time :).

Comment: So, what's the end goal?

Comment: I want to be able to view all 3 databases as one, without having to search multiple times to view the data i need

Comment: The 3 .csv files can be found here for reference; https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/25170a92-0736-4090-baea-bf6add82d118/gm-road-casualty-accidents-full-stats19-data

Comment: As end goal I ment: how do you expect the data to look like for given sample

Comment: Ah right, so i wanted to the data to be made into a single table with index to the left and then the data in the same row, however as some of the workbooks have multiple values for the same index VLOOKUP doesnt seem to work

Comment: Please amend your question to include an example of what you want the combined workbook/worksheet to look like.